# Redis Moved issue on Delete for key

Tags: azure, go, redis, redis-cluster

I am using Redis Enterprise on my azure server. I am able to connect to the server and store data in it, and retrieve it.

After retrieving a value like an OTP, I want to delete the specific data but sometimes I get error

```
MOVED 8000 6.xxx.xxx.xxx:8111
```

I am not sure why this error occurs sometimes.

This is how I am creating my redis client in golang

```
client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:      os.Getenv("REDIS_URL"),
        Password:  os.Getenv("REDIS_PASSWORD"),
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12},
    })

    err := client.Ping(context.Background()).Err()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Fatal(err, "failed to connect with redis instance at ", os.Getenv("REDIS_URL"))
    }

    consumer, err := events.NewConsumer(conn, db, client)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    go consumer.Listen()

    referralService := services.NewReferralCodeService(client)
    atHandler := pc.NewUserController(
        pr.NewUserRepository(db, client, referralService),
        events.NewEventEmitter(conn),
        g,
        token.NewTokenRepository(db, client),
        referralService,
    )
```

How I am using it

```
func (r *userRepository) SendUpdateOTP(p *PhoneNumberDTO) (*NotificationData, *errors.Error) {
    otpAllowListEnv := os.Getenv("OTP_ALLOW_LIST")
    defaultOTP := os.Getenv("DEFAULT_OTP")
    env := os.Getenv("APP_ENV")
    otpAllowList := strings.Split(otpAllowListEnv, ",")
    var otp string
    if strings.Contains(strings.Join(otpAllowList, " "), p.PhoneNumber) || env != "production" {
        otp = defaultOTP
    } else {
        otp = utils.GenerateRandomDigits(6)
    }

    err := utils.AddToRedis(r.redisClient, fmt.Sprintf("otp:user:update:%v", p.PhoneNumber), otp)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(err.Error())
    }
    message := fmt.Sprintf("Your Account Update OTP is %v, this is valid for 5 minutes", otp)

    return &NotificationData{
        Recipient: "1" + p.PhoneNumber,
        Message:   &message,
    }, nil
}

func (r *userRepository) UpdatePhoneNumber(gctx *gin.Context, p *PhoneNumberOtpDTO) (*User, *errors.Error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), mongoQueryTimeout)
    defer cancel()

    id, err := middleware.CtxUserIDValuex(gctx)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.NewBadRequestError(err.Error())
    }

    value, errx := utils.GetFromRedis(r.redisClient, fmt.Sprintf("otp:user:update:%v", p.PhoneNumber))
    if errx != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(errx.Error())
    }

    if value != p.Otp {
        return nil, errors.NewBadRequestError("invalid OTP")
    }
    err1 := utils.DeleteFromRedis(r.redisClient, fmt.Sprintf("otp:user:update:%v", p.PhoneNumber))
    if err1 != nil {
        return nil, errors.New(err1.Error())
    }
    query := bson.D{{Key: "_id", Value: id}}
    update := bson.M{
        "$set": bson.M{
            "phoneNumber": p.PhoneNumber,
        },
        "$currentDate": bson.M{"updatedAt": true},
    }
    res := r.collection.FindOneAndUpdate(ctx, query, update, options.FindOneAndUpdate().SetReturnDocument(1))

    var updatedP *User

    if errz := res.Decode(&updatedP); errz != nil {
        if errz.Error() == "mongo: no documents in result" {
            return nil, errors.New("no user with that credentials exist")
        }
        if strings.Contains(errz.Error(), "dup key") {
            return nil, errors.New("Credentials already in use. If this is a mistake, kindly reachout to support.")
        }
        return nil, errors.New("An error occured, kindly try later or check the number.")
    }
    updatedP.Password = ""
    return updatedP, nil
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong here or maybe because I have an enterprise redid running as I never experience this issue locally.

Comment: The error tells you that the server at 6.xxx.xxx.xxx:8111 is responsible for this particular key. Connect to this server and retry the command there. See "Redirection and resharding" in https://redis.io/docs/reference/cluster-spec/. I suspect there are client libraries available that do this automatically.

Comment: Will adding a retry to the client setup solve this? Because I cannot test directly to confirm since this issue is not consistent.

Comment: The set of keys a server handles doesn't change unless servers are added to or removed from the cluster. So sending commands for a particular key to a particular server should either always work directly or always redirect. It shouldn't be inconsistent at all.

Comment: I honestly do not know how to fix this issue and what to leverage here. The documentation I read which you linked did not provide me with any meaningful way to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68232040/23121702
It also mentions using ioredis which takes care of the redirects.